# Find index of all differences at the same position between two numeric vectors

Tags: r, vector, indexing

I'm trying to return the indices of all differences between two numeric vectors *at the same relative index*. I can't believe I'm asking this because surely it's been asked several times before, but the myriad questions about finding differences between vectors almost all relate to using `%in%` or `match` to find the value of any difference, rather than the specific location of any differences between two elements sharing the same index position.

```
v1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
v2 <- c(1,2,4,4,5,7,7,8,9)
```

The desired output shows the indices where an element in `v1` doesn't match the element (at the same index) of `v2`:

```
# [1] 3, 6
```

Comment: `which(v1 != v2)`

Comment: Wow. Rough morning for me, lol. Thanks a lot!